# How to make try / catch continue to work after an error?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

Parser code is available

```
try
{
   id_source = await ParsingAll(0, "#adv_id", "");   
   foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src");
   position = await ParsingAll(0, "div.title.adv-title.newTitle > h1", "");
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error?.Invoke(id_source + "- Error - ");    
}
```

How to do if an error occurs in the string "foto_path", then after processing the try / catch error, the program continued to work and began to execute the string "position"?

Comment: Well the solution depends on whether knowing your requirements for architecture it is acceptable to add try catch *inside* of ParsingAll method. If yes then it's a simple and effective solution

Answer (score 3):

One way is that to add `try` `catch` inside your `ParseAll` method :

```
ParsingAll()
{
   try
   {

   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```

and you can call them normally:

```
id_source = await ParsingAll(0, "#adv_id", "");   
foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src");
position = await ParsingAll(0, "div.title.adv-title.newTitle > h1", "");
```

and return some status with result to tell if it was successful or not.

Or you will need to wrap it separately each of them so that the next statements should execute in case of that one fails:

```
try
{
    foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}

position = await ParsingAll(0, "div.title.adv-title.newTitle > h1", "");
```

But this all depends on the program requirements how the flow will go.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do so is to split the lines into separate `try...catch` clauses:

```
try
{
   id_source = await ParsingAll(0, "#adv_id", "");   
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error?.Invoke(id_source + "- Error - ");    
}
try
{
   foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src"); 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error?.Invoke(id_source + "- Error - ");    
}
…
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just narrow the try-catch block:

Parser code is available

```
// May need its own try-catch blcok
id_source = await ParsingAll(0, "#adv_id", "");

try
{   
    foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src");
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error?.Invoke(id_source + "- Error - ");    
}

// May need its own try-catch blcok
position = await ParsingAll(0, "div.title.adv-title.newTitle > h1", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Get foto_path value from a routine, than has Try catch
Or
put try catch in the ParsingAll routine.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to catch the error within the async ParsingAll method and return only a valid output from that method.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the finally block which will always execute irrespective of exception occurred. I consider this more of a workaround but best solution should be handle it in ParsingAll() method for your situation.

```
try
{
   id_source = await ParsingAll(0, "#adv_id", "");   
   foto_path = await ParsingAll(1, "img[id='print_user_photo']", "src");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Error?.Invoke(id_source + "- Error - ");    
}
finally
{
    position = await ParsingAll(0, "div.title.adv-title.newTitle > h1", "");
}
```